# Publishing to the Windows Store

Tags: windows, store

I'm trying to upload my second submission of an app to the Windows Store.

- Submission 2 status is "A previous submission failed certification. After you submit the latest changes, the submission will go through the certification process again." There's no error message or report that I can check
- Submission 1 never worked, the app was failing to execute even though it passed the initial publishing tests.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The submission status 2 still sounds like it's either expecting you to submit more changes, or it's warning you that recertification is still pending so there's nothing for you to do but wait. However I think you'll need to talk to Microsoft directly about this.

Comment: Were you able to find the solution for this problem?